# Querying installed applications on an iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to query the installed apps on an iPhone for an iPhone app? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

You can't look at a list of installed applications (at least for an app that meets Apple's approval) but you can test whether the phone can open certain URLs using `UIApplicatoin`'s [`-canOpenURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myscheme://test"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:someURL]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then it seems that there is no public API to get the list of installed applications. I really wanted to know if there is possible to create an iPhone app that can create the list of apps that are installed on my iPhone and send it in mail or share otherwise with someone else.

Comment: Not on the iPhone, sorry, but you could always parse the iTunes library on your Mac or PC to generate a list of applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a a server into the pic, 
the server will do the job by querying iTunes libraray and return response to iphone app.